# discord.js userinfo command show all roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i am making a userinfo command and I want it to show all roles the user has. For the message sender i am using this: `message.member.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').join(' - ')` but when i use it for the user the message author is mentioning (`let user = message.mentions.users.first()`) this is the code :
`user.member.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').join(' - ')` it gives this error: `Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined` I have asked on the discord.js discord but they weren't able to help me, Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: try `user.roles.cache ...` instead of `user.member.roles.cache ...`. A user probably does not have a "member" like a message.

Comment: That's wrong @MauriceNino. A `user` object neither have a `member` property nor a `roles` property. They are trying to get the `member` using the `user` object, when they can directly get the `member` from the `message.mentions`

Comment: Yeah well, it was just a guess, as `user.member` just felt wrong. Wasn't meant to be taken as a solution, rather as a hint. @ShubhamParihar

Comment: No problem @MauriceNino. I hope I did not sound like a `prick`. Just wanted to make sure we don't provide any wrong information to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because `user` does not have a property called `member`. If you want to get the mentioned member, use this:

`let member = message.mentions.members.first()`